# Best practice to read limited length from an input stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have packets that are sent over sockets which are preceded by length headers. So every transmission comes with 4 bytes of length information followed by the packet. Therefore, I must limit my `read()` to never exceed the length, so that I don't accidentally read the next packet in line.

`InputStream in` is the input stream, `ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream` is the stream I write incoming packets into and `int len` is the length of an incoming transmission.

Here is what I came up with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    byteStream.write(in.read());
}
```

This is absolutely horrific; reading bytes one by one. I was hoping to see if there is a better way of doing this using buffers (kind of similar to the canonical way of copying streams).

Comment: Read the number of bytes into an array based on your requirements.  If you know the maximum length of the packet it becomes easier as you only need to declare the array once, other wise you will need to create a new array for each packet, take a look at [`InputStream#read(byte[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the input stream in a [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and then use the readInt() and [readFully()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5B%5D%29) methods to get the size and bytes of data out.

```
int len = dis.readInt();
// assuming relatively small byte arrays, use smarter logic for huge streams....
byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
dis.readFully(buffer);
byteStream.write(buffer);
```

Comment: Included example now.

Comment: Ahhhh, right, I thought you couldn't declare variable array size at runtime (something left in my mind from C89).

Comment: Re-reading my answer I can understand why what I wrote does not depict what I thought I was saying... will edit.

Comment: wouldn't `new byte[len]` be an issue in terms of performance? if `len` is big, it might create problems when allocating the array, no?

Comment: Yes, it may be, so, smarter things to do would be to build and reuse a smaller buffer, and then loop through the input using the `readFully(byte[], 0, partlen);` variant as many times as you need, where partlen is the full buffer-size except for the last time though the loop.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how I implemented it yesterday, with a buffer of 8192 bytes.